Photo of an actual piece of spin glass?
I can't find any picture anywhere of a physical spin-glass, such as the Copper-Manganese alloy (CuMn) with 1 a.t.%, or the AuFe. Can someone post an image of physical spin glasses? I am just confused because despite their prevalence I have never seen a picture of them.

Does this count? From Nature - Spin-glass-like freezing of inner and outer surface layers in hollow γ-Fe2O3 nanoparticles


I wonder if the rarity of published photos of these systems is simply because the key experiments happened in the 1970s. Anyway, the book chapter Kawamura, H., & Taniguchi, T. (2015). "Spin glasses". In K.H.J. Buschow (ed.) Handbook of magnetic materials (Vol. 24, pp. 1-137). Elsevier. contains Figure 2, which shows a not very detailed photograph of a sample of the related canonical spin glass compound PtMn. At least it's something.

Not including the actual picture in the post because of licensing; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327568/552049
